# JNA finding window, but not minimizing it

Tags: java, winapi, window, jna

I'm trying to manipulate an external window on Java, with JNA. I want to find a specific window and then minimize it. Every window that I've tried worked well but one (obviously the one that I need). That one can be found and set to the foreground, but can not be minimized programmatically. I've also tried to move it with User32.INSTANCE.MoveWindow, but that command failed too.
I was wondering if there are applications that do not allow JNA window manipulations. If so, what can I do? My code is shown below.

```
    HWND test = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null,"windowname");
    User32.INSTANCE.SetForegroundWindow(test);
    User32.INSTANCE.ShowWindow(test, WinUser.SW_MINIMIZE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [API for ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow):

> nCmdShow
>
> Type: int
>
> Controls how the window is to be shown. **This parameter is ignored the first time an application calls ShowWindow**, if the program that launched the application provides a STARTUPINFO structure. Otherwise, the first time ShowWindow is called, the value should be the value obtained by the WinMain function in its nCmdShow parameter. **In subsequent calls, this parameter can be one of the following values.**

It would seem to be that your minimize command may work if you call it a second time.